# Having issues attempting to backup some old CD Roms

Tags: virtual-machine, burning, ripping, cd, rom

I've been trying to find a way to back up some of my CD Roms by copying their files onto my computer, but that doesn't actually let me use them when I remove the CD, as it seems to check whether the disk is put it, so I tried various programs, all of which usually seem to face errors, probably with the encryption. And then theres programs that dont even seem to recognize my CD at all.

Is there any way I can get around this? Many tutorials make it seem so easy but theres usually some critical step that makes it just not work for me.

For example, I tried to use ImgBurn, but it told me there was an Interpretation/Chrck Condition Error(?), and a L-EC Uncorrectable Error. Most other programs like it just dont keep going for more than 80%. And most also don't give me any error message, other than there being "Read Errors".

At least the program PowerISO gave me an error message about its trial version not being able to create ISOs that big, though it would probably also have that same 80% error. And then I used something called MagicISO, which just didn't recognize the CD in my driver at all.

And I also tried Alcohol120%, but because of worries about Spywarey I dont really want it on my actual PC. So I tried it with my Virtual Machine but if I use shared folders to share my Disk Drive with my VM, it doesn't recognize it as a Disk Drive.

Comment: What errors exactly are you receiving?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to back up?  If, as I suspect, its old games, there are some games you simply can't back up and have them work, you need to crack the game (or more realistically, find a cracked copy or equivalent)

Comment: This really takes me back... IIRC you may need specialized imaging software like Alchol120%/dvddecryptor and emulation software like daemontools/virtualclonecd. I seem to recall using a utility to tell me what DRM was on a disk, but i'm completely not coming up with a utility name. Man, now I feel old...

Comment: @FrankThomas Yeah, I still had hair back then, I think :-D

Comment: Make a [RAW image](https://www.disk-image.com/image_types.htm) iso of the CD... then you should be able to mount it as a _virtual cd drive_ on your virtual machine, e.g. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with the correct (probably old) OS.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running programs that check if the CD is inserted, sometimes those can be accomodated by running a program that pretends to be a CD drive to Windows.

Virtual Clone Drive is an example of this type of software.

The content from the CD needs to be packed into a single large .ISO file - you can use ImgBurn to create an .ISO directly from a CD.

Some applications check for emulated CD drives and won't be fooled, but this seems to work well for some older software.

Comment: This what I have done for years, works perfectly.